# "Isometrically isomorphic" Hilbert spaces: norm equivalence?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

The quotient space $L^2/M$ is isometrically isomorphic to $M^\perp$.

Let $M=\mathbb{R}$ and $[x] = x + \mathbb{R}$ for some  $x \in M^\perp$.

Q1: Does the norm equivalence:
$$ C_1\|x\|_{L^2} \leq \|[x]\|_{L^2/M} \leq C_2\|x\|_{L^2} $$
hold?

Q2: Is there a good literature source where I could read more about isomorphisms on Hilbert spaces?

Comment: What is $\|x\|_{M^\perp}$?

Comment: It's $\|x\|_{L^2}$. (I edited the question)

Comment: The left-hand inequality is obviously false when $x \in M$.

Comment: Shoot. I meant that $x \in M^\perp$. (I edited the question)

Comment: In that case $ \|x\|_{L^2} =\|[x]\|_{L^2/M} $.

Comment: Aha! But why is $\| [x] \|_{L^2/M}  = \inf_{c \in M} \| x + c \|_{L^2} = \| x \|_{L^2}$?

Comment: $\|x+c\|^{2}=\|x\|^{2}+\|c\|^{2}$.

Comment: I see, that must be due to $\int (x + c)^2 = \int x^2 + \int c^2 + 2\int x\, c =  \int x^2 + \int c^2$ as $x\in M^\perp$ and $c \in M$, and then $\int x\, c = 0$. Many thanks @geetha290krm!